# Nested activation boxes in Rational Modeler?

Tags: uml

Is it possible to create nested activation boxes in [Rational Modeler 7.5](https://www.ibm.com/products)? It always seems to want to merge the boxes together into one.

My use case is an object method that calls another method on the same object. I'd like to show a nested activation box for the second call, superimposed on top of the first.

Here's an example (in mine, message2 would loop back onto sender):

[image]
<sub>(source: [holub.com](https://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/images/sequence.activation2.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The activation bar has been erased from the sequence diagram OMG UML 2 specification. It means that this element is only a graphical element which has no equivalent to the UML model.
The activation bar has therefore been erased from RSA 7.5

I think this activation bar elimination is a mistake. Omondo EclipseUML has refused to erased the activation bar into UML 2.3 so if you need this graphical element then feel free to try this tool.

Comment: I don't understand what you're referring to here... I'm looking at the UML 2.3 spec, and I see this sentence (Superstructure 14.3.19, p. 508): "To depict method activations we apply a thin grey or white rectangle that covers the Lifeline line." Can you clarify?

Comment: The activation bar has been erased from the EclipseUML2 UML 2.3 metamodel. UML sequence diagram is a view of the UML metamodel on which Rational 7.5 is built using EMF. So no activation is possible anymore. Too bad ...

Comment: Oh, I see. My question was referring to Rational Modeler (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/modeler/), not Rational Software Architect or Rational Software Modeler. Modeler is based on Rhapsody, not Eclipse.